# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'val' of undefined (ui-nestable.min.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, model-view-controller

I'm facing a minor problem. When I right click on the page and press examine (page's source code) in Google Chrome, I'm getting the error below. This file (ui-nestable.min.js) is required for my page to work properly and the interesting side of it my page works properly. I did research on the internet but did not find any results for this error.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFDJF.png)

ui-nestable.min-js Code:

```
var UINestable = function () {

var updateOutput = function (e) {
    var list = e.length ? e : $(e.target),
        output = list.data('output');
    if (window.JSON) {
        output.val(window.JSON.stringify(list.nestable('serialize'))); //, null, 2));
    } else {
        output.val('JSON browser support required for this demo.');
    }
};


return {
    //main function to initiate the module
    init: function () {

        // activate Nestable for list 1
        $('#nestable_list_1').nestable({
            group: 1
        })
            .on('change', updateOutput);

        // activate Nestable for list 2
        $('#nestable_list_2').nestable({
            group: 1
        })
            .on('change', updateOutput);

        // output initial serialised data
        updateOutput($('#nestable_list_1').data('output', $('#nestable_list_1_output')));
        updateOutput($('#nestable_list_2').data('output', $('#nestable_list_2_output')));

        $('#nestable_list_menu').on('click', function (e) {
            var target = $(e.target),
                action = target.data('action');
            if (action === 'expand-all') {
                $('.dd').nestable('expandAll');
            }
            if (action === 'collapse-all') {
                $('.dd').nestable('collapseAll');
            }
        });

        $('#nestable_list_3').nestable();

    }

};

}();

jQuery(document).ready(function() {    
   UINestable.init();
});
```

Comment: this line ` output.val(window.JSON.stringify(list.nestable('serialize'))); //, null, 2))`  no data found so it is null

Answer (score 0):

you not use all nestable list in your page . 
you must be remove all the extra code .
like that

```
var UINestable = function () {

        var updateOutput = function (e) {
            var list = e.length ? e : $(e.target),
                output = list.data('output');
            if (window.JSON) {
                output.val(window.JSON.stringify(list.nestable('serialize'))); //, null, 2));
            } else {
                output.val('JSON browser support required for this demo.');
            }
        };

        return {
            //main function to initiate the module
            init: function () {

                // activate Nestable for list 1
                $('#nestable_list_1').nestable({
                    group: 1
                }).on('change', updateOutput);

                // output initial serialised data
                updateOutput($('#nestable_list_1').data('output', $('#nestable_list_1_output')));

                $('#nestable_list_menu').on('click', function (e) {
                    var target = $(e.target),
                        action = target.data('action');
                    if (action === 'expand-all') {
                        $('.dd').nestable('expandAll');
                    }
                    if (action === 'collapse-all') {
                        $('.dd').nestable('collapseAll');
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    }();
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {    
       UINestable.init();
    });
```